# Gr-osmosdr installaion error missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR date_time program_options

Tags: arch-linux, boost

I got error while installing gr-osmosdr in Manjaro

```
    cmake ../
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake:223 (message):
  Unable to determine default CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR directory because no
  target architecture is known.  Please enable at least one language before
  including GNUInstallDirs.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Found LOG4CPP: /usr/lib/liblog4cpp.so
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:426 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)
  does not match the name of the calling package (GMP).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:67 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/FindGMP.cmake:1 (include)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/FindMPLIB.cmake:1 (find_package)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake:26 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.7.3") 
-- Checking for module 'gmp'
--   Found gmp, version 6.2.1
-- Found GMP: /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so  
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:426 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)
  does not match the name of the calling package (MPIR).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:67 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/FindMPIR.cmake:1 (include)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/FindMPLIB.cmake:2 (find_package)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake:26 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Checking for module 'mpir >= 3.0'
--   Package 'mpir', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found MPLIB: /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR date_time program_options
  filesystem system regex thread unit_test_framework) (Required is at least
  version "1.75.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2193 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /usr/lib64/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake:45 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/axe/git_clones/gr-osmosdr/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/axe/git_clones/gr-osmosdr/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `boost` package not enough, should be install `boost-lib` in arch based distros